# In iOS 11 Navigation item's titleview, barbutton items are not displaying (Using Xcode 9)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios11

Working in a iPad application(Objective-c), which showed the navigation item's titleview, barbuttonitems in previous iOS versions. But it is not displaying in iOS 11 (Using Xcode 9). I'm using xib not storyboard.

```
self.editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Create Call" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(accountView:)];

[self.editButton setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

self.deleteCallButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(deleteCall:)];

[self.deleteCallButton setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sliderBarItem, self.deleteCallButton, self.emptySeparatorButton1, self.editButton, self.emptySeparatorButton2, self.createOrderButton, nil];
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you post your code?

Comment: show your tried code always

Comment: are you using native default navigation bar or custom ?

Comment: Default navigation bar

Comment: where you added the above code is in inside the viewdidload or else

Comment: inside the viewdidload